# Alternative to mul/mult for multiplication in assembly (MIPS)?

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm implementing a simple single-cycle MIPS processor for a class, and the only operations we implemented are `lw`, `sw`, `j`, `addi`, `or`, `and`, `add`,
`sub`, `beq`, `slt`, `jr`, `andi`, `jal`, `bne` and `sll`. I have to write a MIPS file testing a factorial function. Obviously, I can't use instructions that haven't been implemented but since factorial means: `result = n * factorial(n-1)`, I need a way to multiply two values. Is there a way to do that with the instructions mentioned earlier?

EDIT: I got it working! Here's my MIPS code:

```
multiply:
add   $v1, $0, $0   # initialize result to 0
loop:
beq   $a2, $0, done  # if second operand reaches 0, the multiplication is over
add   $v1, $v1, $a1 # result = result + first operand
addi  $a2, $a2, -1   # decrements second operand
j     loop           # loops
done:           
jr    $ra             # returns to caller
```

Comment: Repeated-addition is one way, taking O(N) time to calculate `M * N`.  Left-shift and add takes O(log2(N)), or just a fixed 32 iterations if you don't do an early-out, although it has branching in the loop to add or not depending on the low bit of the operand you're right-shifting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplication is simply repeated addition, in the same manner that addition is repeated incrementing and exponentiation is repeated multiplication.

Hence you could write a function that multiplies two values as follows (pseudo-code, obviously, but using functions primitive enough for your specifications):

```
def mult (a, b):
    result = 0
    while a > 0:
        result = result + b
        a = a - 1
    return result
```

That's only good for unsigned values as it stands but, since you're doing factorials, you probably don't *need* to concern yourself with negative numbers at all.

In any case, it should be relatively simple to adjust for signed values so, in the interests of completeness, you could use:

```
def mult (a, b):
    # Handle either being zero.

    if a == 0 or b == 0:
        return 0

    # Handle either or both being negative (may
    # need sign change to result).

    sign = 1

    if a < 0:
        a = -a
        sign = -sign

    if b < 0:
        b = -b
        sign = -sign

    # Both now positive, make sure first is not larger (less loops).

    if b < a:
        temp = a
        a = b
        b = temp

    # Multiply small-a by large-b.

    result = 0
    while a > 0:
        result = result + b
        a = a - 1

    # Adjust sign if needed.

    if sign == -1:
        result = -result

    # Et, voila.

    return result
```

Comment: Thank you! I got it! I just wrote a `multiply` function looping additions of the first argument and decrementing the second until it reaches 0 and that did it!

Comment: @SimonBesozzi - it would be faster to use `shift` and `add` for the multiply, which would only need 32 loops. You can do a web search for this to find various examples.

Comment: @rcgldr, that's going to be far less easy to understand, especially since there's no shift-right instruction in the list of allowed ops :-) I suspect, for education, the repeated addition is probably better, leaving bit-twiddling for code that needs maximum performance.

Comment: @paxdiablo - a 32 entry table of bit masks could be used instead of using right shift.